# Forecasting a cumulative variable in time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to build a time series model based on a cumulative variable that never decreases.

I'm interested in knowing when the observable will reach a certain value (i.e., when it will intersect with the blue line in the image below).

[image]

The orange line is fixed to the last known data point and increases based on the average of the last 5 observables.

The red line is not fixed and represents a linear fit based on the last 5 observables. This seems problematic because in Time Period 108 in the graph, the predicted value is less than the observable in the previous time period, which will never physically happen.

The green line is not fixed and represents a linear fit based on all observables.

I'm wondering if someone can suggest an alternative/better approach to modelling this type of situation.

Comment: This is a modelling question and may find a better home on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Imo.

I would suggest to following:
You can estimate the linear increase per time period, using all your data, or an appropriate subset (last 5 observations). Then, predict the values for the out-of-sample period, using the observation in time period 107.
If, for example, your increase per time period is 20 (dx/dt), and your last known observation at time T has the value of 200 (x), then x would be 220 at time T + 1.

Hence, you would apply your solution in the green line, but shift a bit up to start at your last observation.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what the orange line is

Comment: Your orange line is the average increase over the last 5 observations, right? I suggested to apply a regression on all your data points, and then use the beta coefficient as increase delta in your prediction. Does this help you?

Comment: I think I understand now. Fit a linear model based on the last 5 or all observations, then just shift up so that it intersects the last known observation?

Comment: Jup. Or, in other words. Start your prediction at the last observation and increase the value with beta for every time period. That would be the most appropriate way in my opinion.

Comment: Makes sense. So if I shift the red line up so that it intersects, can you think of why there would be such a large discrepancy between it and the orange line, which are both based on the last 5 time periods? I still feel like there's something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing

Comment: Your orange line is based on the average, hence minimizing the absolute difference between the estimate and the observation. Your regression is based on minimizing the mean squared error, which is a different loss function. This means that outliers are more important in regressions than they are in your average increase solution. Note that one is not "better" than the other, just a different way of estimating!

Comment: I was just reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean#Motivating_properties. Specifically this caught my eye: "the arithmetic mean of the numbers does this best, in the sense of minimizing the sum of squared deviations from the typical value". Based on this, it is suggesting both mean and linear regression are second-order operations?